# x:Bind Data Validation

Tags: validation, data-binding, inotifypropertychanged, uwp-xaml

I'm using `x:Bind` and `INotifyPropertyChanged` in a Windows Universal App to bind a class property to a `TextBox` embedded in a `ListView` control. The class property is of type `double`, and I want to prevent the user from entering a `string`. The problem I'm having is that with two way data binding, an exception is thrown the before I can handle it when the user enters invalid input.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can validate it in your two way bindig properties set method. Something like this:

```
private double number;
public double Number
{
    get
    {
        return number;
    }
    set
    {
        double tempNumber;
        if (double.TryParse(value.ToString(), out tempNumber))
        {
            number = value;
        }
        else
        {
            number = 0.0;
        }

        RaisePropertyChange(nameof(Number));
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It looks like it's still throwing the exception because it expects 'value' to be a 'double' when it comes in.

Comment: Please post the relevant parts of your code and the exception message.

Answer (score 0):

I can't write a comment, so: what about using a value converter in your binding? TextBox control only accept strings as its value, so if you want a double in your ViewModel/Code-Behind you need to use a value converter that parse the TextBox's string value to a double and vice-versa.

The converter can be something like this:

```
public class DoubleToStringConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        return value.ToString()
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        var parsed = false;
        var parsedValue = 0.0;
        if (double.TryParse(value.ToString(), out parsedValue)
        {
            return parsedValue;
        }
        else
        {
            return -1.0;
        }
    }
}
```

For validation you can define a range of "valid values" and check it out in your ViewModel when the properties changed